# Ruby detects variable is string, but ends the script without breaking loop

Tags: ruby

code:

```
a = rand(1..100)
puts "Guess a number from 1 through 100!"
i = 0
loop do 
    i = i+1
    b = gets.chomp
        if b.is_a? String
        puts "Only numerical values"
    end
    if b == a
        puts "Good Job! You finished in #{i} attempts!"
        break
    end
    if b<a 
        puts "Too Low!"
    end
    if b>a
        puts "Too High!"
    end
    if b<0
        puts "Please input numbers above 0!"
    end

end
```

Error Message:

```
Guess a number from 1 through 100!
hi
Only numerical values
hi-lo.rb:14:in `<': comparison of String with 38 failed (ArgumentError)
from hi-lo.rb:14:in `block in <main>'
from hi-lo.rb:4:in `loop'
from hi-lo.rb:4:in `<main>'
```

My problem:
basically, i want to make it so that ruby will detect when someone inputs a string instead of an integer. Thus resulting in outputting a message that states that you have entered an illegal character. It detects i am entering a string, but it shuts down the code instead of continuing the loop. Any advice? Thanks.

Comment: Side note, this is only displaying the message because i used gets.chomp instead of gets.chomp.to_i

Comment: Using gets.chomp results in stopping any if statement.

Comment: Use `next` to go to next item of the `loop`, or `break` to exit.

Comment: BTW `gets.chomp` will always be `String`.

Comment: And `gets.chomp.to_i` will always be an integer. Something more complicated is needed here (as in the linked answer, for example)

Comment: i can use the next feature but how do i make it output the message. I am using gets.chomp.to_i